# How do kernel versions work on Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, kernel

I know that the kernel installed by `apt` is version `5.x`. I want to know what does the number in between the two dashes means and also what is `generic`. For example: `5.x.x-yy-generic`.

Comment: Did you try using a search engine?  My answer was the first entry on a search; though tend to use a `site:*.ubuntu.com` to restrict results to official sources where I have more trust with accuracy.

Comment: the website is very confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://ubuntu.com/kernel

> The easiest way to determine the kernel you’re running is to type cat
> /proc/version_signature on the terminal. For example:
>
> $ cat /proc/version_signature
>
> Ubuntu 5.4.0-12.15-generic 5.4.8
>
> This output provides important information about the kernel:
>
> ```
> Canonical adds "Ubuntu"
> Ubuntu kernel-release = 5.4.0-12.15-generic
>     kernel version is 5.4, which is identical to upstream stable kernel version
>     .0 is an obsolete parameter left over from older upstream kernel version naming practices
>     -12 application binary interface (ABI) bump for this kernel
>     .15 upload number for this kernel
>     -generic is kernel flavour parameter, where -generic is the default Ubuntu kernel flavour
> Mainline kernel-version = 5.4.8
> ```

Comment: Now arises the question of "what is Mainline kernel-version?"

Comment: Upstream version number, and not a Ubuntu specified value. That wasn't in the question, and would have thought it was obvious.

Comment: what's ABI, upload number and flavour parameter?

Comment: Mainline version was just released, I think

Comment: I can just read up more

Comment: @guiverc Thanks anyway!

Comment: ABI = application binary interface... the interface between kernel & user-space.  Why modules (aka drivers) need to be recompiled for newer kernels, otherwise the ABI won't match and you'll risk/get kernel panic et.al.